# Image is not showing with the linear-gradient when parent has a background-color

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div.parent with a background-color:white and a div with an image in it.

I set a linear-gradient on the div.img-container

What I need is to have a container with a background-color:white, and a background-linear gradient on the image. I need the 2 "parents". I don't know what i'm missing, it works fine when I have only one div..

```css
.parent{
  background-color:grey;
}

.img-container{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 100%);
margin:auto;
}

.my-img{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="img-container">
   <img class="my-img" src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/05/1454345014-capture-d-ecran-2016-02-01-a-17-43-28.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The image is not showing because of this line:  .my-img { z-index: -1; } Are you trying to have the gradient on top of the image and still see the image??

Comment: thats right, i need a gradient only on the image, but i found my answer thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution, without messing with z-index and absolute positioning on the main element/parent, is using a pseudo.

This way it will flow nice with the rest of the content.

```css
.parent{
  background-color:grey;
}
.img-container{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  margin:auto;
  position: relative;
}
.img-container:after{
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 100%);
}
.my-img{
  display:block;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img class="my-img" src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/05/1454345014-capture-d-ecran-2016-02-01-a-17-43-28.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you man thats what i needed, it works like a charm. I just added some z-index cause I have multiple child.

Comment: @teddym You're welcome, and please accept the most appropriate answer as well.

Comment: i dont have enough reputation to do that, once i have it i'll do it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `position: absolute` and apply a lower `z-index` for `.parent` as apposed to `.my-img`:

```
.parent {
  background-color: grey;
  z-index: -2;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.img-container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 100%);
  margin: auto;
}

.my-img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Check [it](https://jsfiddle.net/9vsrktua/) out.